# Cambiar atributos de las etiquetas de html desde un template que hereda el contenido desde un archivo base.html

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Tengo un template `base.html` del cual el resto de mi templates lo expanden mediante la etiqueta `extends`, un ejemplo del código del archivo `base.html` es el siguiente:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Como me estoy usando `bootstrap` debo definir ciertas clases a algunos tag de html. Mí problema es el siguiente me gustaría que en **un** solo template, por ejemplo, `login.html` pueda sobreescribir la clase del body para que sea afectado solo en ese template, el código del archivo `login.html` es:

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}
 {% load static %}
 {% block title %} Título {% endblock %}
 {% block content %}
       ....
 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el base.html podrías poner:

```
<body class="{% block body_class%}hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini{% endblock %}">
```

y en el login.html agregas:

```
{% block body_class%}login_body_class{% endblock %}
```

El html resultante en el login.html será:

```
<body class="login_body_class">
```

En otros templates si no agregas ese bloque se vera asi:

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
```

Comment: Lo que dices funciona casi, pero aparece el texto `login_body_class` dentro del contenido del body del archivo `login.html`

Comment: como en la imagen [imagen] (http://imgur.com/ey8vEhg)

Comment: Deberia funcionar. Checkea que lo tengas como en mi imagen https://imgur.com/a/Mkkqk

Comment: Eso Funcionó te lo agradezco mucho, el problema era que habia configurado el block dentro del body